# Problem to display dynamic rows in table layout : Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, tablelayout

I want to show data in table layout. Number of data is dynamic, so I need to implement dynamic rows in table. For this purpose I want to show 4 TextView in a single row.

***Problem***

Currently, I am able to show data in table and with four TextView, but I want some spaces between all four EditText, but unable to do it.

Here is my code

```
for(ItemRow row : this.getRows()) {

                if(row != null) {
                    // delcare a new row
                    newRow = new TableRow(this);
                    newRow.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    newRow.setPadding(0, 2, 0, 2);

                    column1 = new TextView(this);
                    column2 = new TextView(this);
                    column3 = new TextView(this);
                    column4 = new TextView(this);

                    column1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    column2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    column3.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    column4.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    column1.setSingleLine(false);
                    column2.setSingleLine(false);
                    column3.setSingleLine(false);
                    column4.setSingleLine(false);

                    if(row.getColumnOne() != null){
                        column1.setText(row.getColumnOne());
                    } 

                    if(row.getColumnTwo() != null) {
                        column2.setText(row.getColumnTwo());
                    }

                    if(row.getColumnThree() != null) {
                        column3.setText(row.getColumnThree());
                    }

                    if(row.getColumnFour() != null) {
                        column4.setText(row.getColumnFour());
                    }

                    //Now add a row 
                    newRow.addView(column1);
                    newRow.addView(column2);
                    newRow.addView(column3);
                    newRow.addView(column4);
                    //Add row to table
                    table.addView(newRow, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                }
            }
```

And here is my output :

[image]

***Need***

I need spaces between columns. How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set padding left 5dp for every textveiw widget like `android:paddingLeft="5dp"`

Answer (score 2):

You have to add paddind for columns too as:

```
column1.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);    
column2.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);    
column3.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);    
column4.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
```

Edits: 
    Then you can set layoutparams as follows:

```
column1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(60,90));
```

Comment: but how to set multi line in text view of custom row? Because texts in textview are very large and then row get to long with single line.

Comment: Then you can setLayoutParams for TextView like     column1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(60,90));